# how to solve knapsack problem with final total capcity exactly at certain number

Tags: knapsack-problem

There are n items with positive integer values and sizes, and a positive integer capacity W. Each item can only be chosen once. The problem is to compute the max-value set of items with total size exactly W. If no such set exists, the algorithm should correctly detect that fact.

Is there a method to solve this problem?